# Default article-like classes with compact bibliography

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, fontsize

In most academic journal styles, the bibliography is typeset in a much more compact fashion than in the usual classes. Compare for instance these two:

[image]

[image]

The former is obtained with `siamltex.cls`, the latter from `article.cls`. I would like to obtain something that resembles the former, without using a class from a specific journal: the journal classes include lots of quirks for author and title formatting, and generally tend to be old, badly written and incompatible one with each other and with many modern packages.

So I would like to have the benefits of "standard" classes (like `article.cls`, `paper.cls` or `scrartcl.cls`), together with a more compact typesetting. I am focusing here on the bibliography, but there are also some other small details such as the font size for the paper title.

> Are there any standard documentclasses that allow for a more compact display of the bibliography? Or, alternatively, are there any additional packages that alter the aspect of the standard classes to obtain a more compact look (possibly not as extreme as `savetrees.sty`)?

Comment: the class `amsart` does set the size of biblio entries to `\footnotesize`.  it also allows a user to change the size by `\renewcommand{\bibliofont}{<font spec>}`.

Comment: I don't see too much difference, apart from the smaller type size and the hanging indentation. For the `article` class it's just a matter of patching the `thebibliography` environment or just issuing `\footnotesize` before the references.

Comment: The other thing that makes a large difference is the spacing between successive entries. I know that I can change most of these things by hand, but I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel every time with low-level TeX code. In my eyes it would be nicer to have a class that sets everything up in a compatible and typographically nice way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `natbib` the two parameters you need to change the space between the various entries and the fonts are `\bibsep` and `\bibfont`. You can change them using

```
\setlength{\bibsep}{1pt} % or use whatever dimension you want
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small} % or any other  appropriate font command
```

In `biblatex` the equivalent parameters are `\bibitemsep` and `\bibfont`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to emulate the bibliography design by the `siamltex` class, just copy in your document the relevant part of the class; I'll make some changes to correct a couple of mistakes.

```
\makeatletter
\newdimen\bibindent
\bibindent=16pt
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
  {\par\bigskip\footnotesize
   \section*{\centering\normalfont\footnotesize\MakeUppercase{\refname}}
   \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}
   \list{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumi}}}%
        {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
         \leftmargin\labelwidth
         \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
         \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
         \itemindent -\bibindent
         \listparindent \itemindent
         \parsep \z@
         \usecounter{enumi}%
         \let\p@enumi\@empty
         \renewcommand\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}}}%
     \renewcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em \@plus.33em \@minus.07em}%
     \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000%
     \frenchspacing\footnotesize}
  {\def\@noitemerr
     {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
   \endlist}
\makeatother
```